# npm - a package's 6th level dependency is shown to be using outdated version by snyk

Tags: npm, snyk

In my node.js project, I have dependency on `packageA`. Since this package is archived now, I had to override one of it's dependencies (not sure if this is relevant). My package.json looks like this-

```
...
  "dependencies": {
    "packageA": "1.4.39"
    ...
  }
  "overrides": {
    "packageA": {
      "nconf": "0.11.4"
    }
  },
...
```

When I run `snyk test` to detect vulnerabilities, it shows the following-

```
✗ Regular Expression Denial of Service (ReDoS) [High Severity][https://security.snyk.io/vuln/SNYK-JS-ANSIREGEX-1583908] in ansi-regex@2.1.1
    introduced by packageA@1.4.39 > nconf@0.11.4 > yargs@16.2.0 > cliui@7.0.4 > string-width@4.2.3 > strip-ansi@3.0.1 > ansi-regex@2.1.1 and 17 other path(s)
  This issue was fixed in versions: 3.0.1, 4.1.1, 5.0.1, 6.0.1
```

So `strip-ansi@3.0.1` is using `ansi-regex@2.1.1`, which should be updated. But if I run `npm show strip-ansi@6.0.1`, the output is like this-

```
...
dependencies:
ansi-regex: ^5.0.1 
...
```

So `strip-ansi@6.0.1` is not really dependant on that old version. However, the problem is not probably with `snyk`. Just that somehow my `package-lock.json` file is including an old version.

If I run `npm update packageA`, nothing happens - it's already up-to-date.

If I search `package-lock.json` file for all reference to `ansi-regex@2.1.1`, delete those, and then run `npm install`, it just goes back to the previous state.

I also tried deleting the `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` file and ran `npm install` after cleaning cache. This seems to solve the problem, but that also updates the whole `package-lock.json` file, which should be risky in production environment.

Any suggestions how I can fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you wrote, the problem is the state of the package `lockfile`.
A suggestion is to pin the `ansi-regex` package to `version 3.0.1` which is noted as fixed by Snyk. You can achieve it like this:

```
"overrides": {
  "ansi-regex": "3.0.1",
}
```

And to then try an `npm install` to make the update and follow that with a `snyk test` to ensure versions are not free of vulns.

Also a suggestion to better understand what is happening in general is to run a `snyk monitor` command instead instead of `snyk test`?

Or, even better, scan from the `Snyk UI in a direct SCM integration`?
It is a good practice to run `npm install` before (no need to delete `node_modules`).
It may be more comprehensive than a CLI local results I think.

This would show you the project view with a clear dependency tree & hierarchy and would maybe help you identify the problem.

Hopefully this will give you a visualization of where the `ansi-regex@2.1.1` is pulled from and **Snyk** will provide you with a suggestion for a fix.

Hope it's helpful

Comment: `overrides` worked. Thanks!

Comment: thanks for the confirmation @JohnReese. Out of curiosity, in the Snyk UI, does the visualization help you? to see the dependency tree?